# Mechanical waves: How is the energy stored towards fixed end?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

An incoming wave pulse and reflected wave can interfare to give straight string near to fixed end. Then how exactly is the potential energy stored in it?

Comment: See if my rewording of your question is what you wanted to ask--if instead it was about sinusoidal waves then see the links I provided.